# Moving Average Time Series Minutes Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, moving-average

In this problem, I am trying to get moving averages in this dataframe.
There are different number of transactions happening each minute. Corresponding to each transaction, i am trying to get MA of all the flow values happening in previous 2 minutes of that transaction( Assume at time t)

```py
m = timedelta(minutes = 1)
for dt in df.DateTime: # for dt time row in datetime column
    obs(dt-m)= Flow(df.iloc[dt-m,1]).mean #Calculate mean of flow values happening at one minute before dt time
    obs(dt-m*2)= GPL_Density(df.iloc[dt-m*2,1]).mean #Calculate mean of flow values happening at two minutes before dt time
    df.loc[df.GPL_Density]= (obs(dt-m),obs(dt-m*2)).mean
```

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
DateTime    Flow
1/11/2017 6:01  600
1/11/2017 6:01  600
1/11/2017 6:02  600
1/11/2017 6:02  600
1/11/2017 6:02  600
1/11/2017 6:02  600
1/11/2017 6:03  780
1/11/2017 6:03  780
1/11/2017 6:03  780
1/11/2017 6:04  480





````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? What are issues you run into? What parts don't you understand and what parts do you understand?

Comment: I am trying to iterate in Datetime column using for loop. For example- at each transaction happening at time T, it checks the transactions happened in last T-1,T-2 and T-3 minutes. Then returning the average value of speed, flow and density of all the transactions in those (T-1,T-2,T-3) rows. Here T refers at a minute level.

Comment: I am new to programming, so learning about timedelta in datetime library. Need help with formulation.